# Cannot add more elements to NSSegmentedControl

Tags: macos, cocoa, nssegmentedcontrol

I have this `NSSegmentedControl` created on interface builder and saved on a xib file. The control has initially 4 segments.

If I use this

```
[self.myControl setSegmentCount:6];
```

to increase the number of segments to 6, programmatically, it will not work but if I do

```
[self.myControl setSegmentCount:2];
```

to reduce the number of segments to 2, it works.

if after that I return the number of segments to 4, it works, but I cannot pass the number of segments defined on interface builder.

Any clues?

Comment: Are you sure the segments aren't being clipped or that there's enough room for them? You should try enabling auto sizing for them

Comment: how do I do that on interface builder?

Comment: I've never used NSSegmentedControl but I think if you can select an individual segment in interface builder, you can then click on the little ruler icon in the right hand sidebar and there should be autosizing options there

Comment: that's it. Your comment lead me to the answer that is the lack of constraints on the control. Add your comment as an answer and I will accept that. Thanks.

Comment: Actually I just read the NSSegmentedControl documentation and if you set the width of a segment to 0, it will automatically resize it to fit the contents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select a segment in interface builder and click on the little ruler in the right hand sidebar to add layout constraints and prevent clipping